# How to convert a REQUEST response to Ruby nested Hash/Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, json, hash

I'm using HTTParty to do an external API call like so:

```
@result = HTTParty.get('some/url')
```

The result is a 3/4 layers nested JSON object with arrays (the result is not always the same though, some times there are more nested objects, some times more arrays, some times no arrays, etc but it always either nested objects nested objects with arrays):

```
  {
  "something": "10100014",
  "something": "025MH-V0625",
  "something": null,
  "something": null,
  "something": "SALE",
  "nested": {
    "something": "DETACHED_HOUSE",
    "something": null,
    "something": "2014",
    "something": 0,
    "something": 138,
    "something": 0,
    "something": null,
    "something": "A2010",
    "something": "M2",
    "nested": {
      "something": "Tværagervej",
      "something": "34A",
      "something": "",
      "something": null,
      "something": "København S",
      "something": "2300",
      "something": "DK"
    }
    ...
}
```

Now I need to iterate over key/values (including nested key/values) of the result but when I do:

```
@result.respond_to?(:each)
```

or

```
@result["nested"].respond_to?(:each)
```

I get a `false`. I've also tried:

```
@n_result = @result.to_json
```

and

```
@n_result = JSON.parse(@result)
```

But I get the `false` in both cases. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This response does not seem to be a valid JSON, surrounding `{` and `}` are missing. Didn't `JSON.parse` returned any exception? I've tried offline:

```
@result = %Q{
  {
    "something": "10100014",
    "something": "025MH-V0625",
    "something": null,
    "something": null,
    "something": "SALE",
    "nested": {
      "something": "DETACHED_HOUSE",
      "something": null,
      "something": "2014",
      "something": 0,
      "something": 138,
      "something": 0,
      "something": null,
      "something": "A2010",
      "something": "M2",
      "nested": {
        "something": "Tværagervej",
        "something": "34A",
        "something": "",
        "something": null,
        "something": "København S",
        "something": "2300",
        "something": "DK"
      }
      }
  }
}
```

And then:

```
@result_r = JSON.parse(@result)
```

returns:

```
 => {"something"=>"SALE", "nested"=>{"something"=>"M2", "nested"=>{"something"=>"DK"}}}
```

Of course duplicate keys has been skipped.

Let you try:

```
@result_r = JSON.parse("{%s}" % @result)
```

Comment: My bad, the badly constructed JSON is my fault. Let's assume the response has a proper JSON, would `JSON.parse` work?

Comment: Yes, of course. If something goes wrong, paste the result here to look through why.